# Emacs: Prevent TRAMP connection closing

Tags: emacs, ftp, tramp

I'm using emacs with TRAMP ( C-x C-f /ftp:user@site.com:/ ), and randomly, sometimes ten minutes, sometimes, ~12 seconds (no exaggerating) my connection will close (I think). I'll try to type, or list a dir, and it will say "Opening FTP connection to site.com...". Is there a way to tell it to just keep the connection open until I exit? Or is it the webserver killing the connection? I'm just using standard FTP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test, try using FTP by hand.  FTP to your site on the command line, do a few things, then wait about 30 seconds or so, and see if it disconnects you.  I remember one webhosting firm timed me out very fast.

As to tramp, the only thing I can see is the user option [tramp-completion-reread-directory-timeout](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#index-tramp_002dcompletion_002dreread_002ddirectory_002dtimeout-180).  Maybe it wonders if someone else changed the directory and rereads it to be sure.